# Duplicate integers in an array

Tags: java, array, hash-map, set

Code shows duplicate values of integers in an array with indexes and the number of occurrences. Can you please critique my code and provide your thoughts on where I should improve my code?

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class DuplicatesInAnArray {

    private static class ShowIndexDuplicateData<T> {
        private static final String NEW_LINE = System
                .getProperty("line.separator");
        private Set<T> indices;
        private int count;

        public ShowIndexDuplicateData(Set<T> indices, int count) {
            this.indices = indices;
            this.count = count;
        }

        public Set<T> getIndices() {
            return indices;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("Count: ").append(getCount()).append(" Indices: ")
                    .append(getIndices()).append(NEW_LINE);

            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    public static void duplicatesInAnArray(Integer[] array) {
        if (array == null || array.length <= 1) {
            System.out.println("");
        }

        Map<Integer, ShowIndexDuplicateData<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {

            if (map.containsKey(array[i])) {
                ShowIndexDuplicateData<Integer> showIndexDuplicateData = map
                        .get(array[i]);
                showIndexDuplicateData.count++;
                showIndexDuplicateData.indices.add(i);
            } else {
                int count = 1;
                Set<Integer> indices = new HashSet<>();
                indices.add(i);
                ShowIndexDuplicateData<Integer> showIndexDuplicateData = new ShowIndexDuplicateData<>(
                        indices, count);
                map.put(array[i], showIndexDuplicateData);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(map);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] array = { 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 3, 6, 1 };
        DuplicatesInAnArray.duplicatesInAnArray(array);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you on Java 8?

Comment: @h.j.k. : yes i am.

Comment: Wells you got a pretty great [Java 8 answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/102279/27975) there... :)

Answer (score 8):

1. You don't need to use `Set` since indexes can never repeat.  Use a `List` isntead.
2. You don't need to keep track of the `count`.  You can just get `indices.size()`.  That makes `ShowIndexDuplicateData` class unnecessary.
3. You probably should be dealing with `int[]` rather than `Integer[]`.  There aren't many reasons to have a `Integer[]`

With that, you can really simplify this (using java 8):

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
.....


static final String FORMAT = "%s: count=%s, indices=%s%n";  

public static void duplicatesInArray(int[] ary) {
    IntStream.range(0,ary.length).boxed()
            .collect(groupingBy(i -> ary[i], toList()))
            .forEach((num, lst) -> System.out.printf(FORMAT, num, lst.size(), lst));
}
```